# Return true if a function has ran correctly

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming

so I have a functions called `Single<List<Settings>> runUpgrade(Context context)` in a class called `UpgradeHelper` where Single is imported from `import io.reactivex.Single`. I need to check in my `ContentProvider` if the `runUpgrade(Context context)` method was successful in executing the upgrade and return `true` if it was otherwise return `false`.

I have created another boolean function called `boolean checkUpgradeSuccess()` but I am confused as to how I can check for the success of the upgrade?

My code for the `checkUpgradeSuccess()` is as follows so far, but I don't know how to move forward:

```
private boolean checkMigrationSuccess(){
       UpgradeHelper uHelper = new UpgradeHelper();
       
       uHelper.runUpgrade(getContext());

        return true;
    }
```

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If the method `Single<List<Settings>>` returns something (looks like), why don't you check the result (empty, `null`, `Exception` thrown or invalid entries etc.) and `return true` if it is valid?

Comment: @deHaar I see what you mean, because the `Single<List<Settings>>` stores database values from a database which I am migrating to another database, so I need to check if everything is there in the list, checking if it is not empty can work but what if some other values are missing?

Comment: How is this related to rxjava or reactive programming?

Comment: This is not idiomatic. Simply _throw an exception_ if there is an error, and return (void) if there is no problem.

Comment: @DaveNewton I thought it might be relevant since I am using the import from reactivex.Single, my bad.

Comment: You have to know that to check, otherwise you need to do some micro requirements engineering and ask someone who knows. We can't know how to do a content validation (if there is content and no error).

Comment: @deHaar completely understand that, but earlier comment helped me understand better, it is something simple, that I was over-complicating.

Answer (score 1):

runUpgrade method should return result info such as success, error etc about upgrade status. Also i highly recommend to separate the methods as migrate and checkStatus because you may need to check the status many times after migration.

```
 private isSuccess:Boolean = false;

 private boolean migrate(){
           UpgradeHelper uHelper = new UpgradeHelper();
           isSuccess = uHelper.runUpgrade(getContext());
        }

 private boolean checkStatus(){
   return isSuccess;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about working with exceptions? Create your own xxxExcption and put your code in

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```